# How can I print the template lines in a in Word 2007 template?

Tags: microsoft-word, printer, printing, microsoft-word-2007

I'd like to print the label outlines from [this Word label template](http://www.avery.co.uk/vgnfiles/uk/A-0003-01_P.doc) onto some plain paper, but no matter what I try I cannot make them print; if I enter text into the template, the text prints fine (thus ruling out printer/ink issues), but the outlines never print.

Even the print preview shows the label outlines, but when I print—nothing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you tried to put a space into the template?

Comment: The outlines _never_ print, even when there is text in the template. I think my question was a bit unclear—I've edited it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gridlines never print. They are there purely for display (and only if you have chosen to display them). To do what you want, you can apply real borders, print, then remove or undo the borders, e.g.:

1. Select the table (click the selection box at top left). This should select the table tools->Design tab.
2. In the Draw borders group at the right, select the line thickness you want (1/4pt is the thinnest) and the line style (e.g. if you want the line to look like the "gridlines", you could select the first dashed line style).
3. At the right of the Table Styles group, click the Borders dropdown and Select "All Borders"
4. Print
5. Undo, or click the Borders dropdown again and select "No border"